# sass --watch is not watching for updates

Tags: cmd, sass, rubygems, command-prompt

I'm on win 10 using sass --v "Sass 3.4.2", sublime text3 for editing sass with a scss plug-in.
when I type sass --watch in cmd it converts the file to css but does not watch for any updates that I make in the scss.

I get this in the command prompt

```
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Try the file in a different directory, I was doing it on the desktop and for some reason which I still can't understand my cmd prompt won't watch on the desktop.

Another method has worked for others, after you run the command, close the .scss file and open it again. this should work now every time you save changes.

Hope that helps